# How to keep the proxy setup active till the end of execution python script execution

Tags: python, proxy

I am trying to write the python code were I want to keep the proxy setting active till th end of the python scrip execution. Is there any sample code exists

Comment: what settings do you want to keep active?

Comment: I want my proxy settings keep active for my entire session

Comment: The below code works for me                                                                                            user = input('Username: ')
passwd = getpass.getpass("Password: ") 
proxy = "@example.com:port no"

httpProxy = "http://" + user + ":" + passwd + proxy
httpsProxy = "https://" + user + ":" + passwd + proxy 

os.environ['http_proxy'] = httpProxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = httpsProxy